# DNS Blocking--Detectable?

Tags: dns, opendns

Our school is using OpenDNS to block harmful sites, torrent downloads, and other file sharing sites. I found out a way to bypass this by changing my dns to Google Public DNS.

My question is, would they be able to find out who uses a different DNS?
And is there a way they can block me again?

Comment: -1 not really a beneficial question, as you are trying to bypass restrictions that are in place by your school...

Comment: Randolph answered the first part of your question. The answer to your second part is also yes, they can block your access to googles DNS in their firewall. Then you have to find *yet* another public DNS which they can block and so on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they can monitor all DNS requests through the firewall based on IP address, and if they've built their network properly, to terminal and logged in user. You're well on your way to suspension and possible expulsion.

Comment: +1, but i liked your last profile picture more...the comment is not relevant to the question at all

Comment: Although it become pretty close to that situation in _Little Brother_...

Comment: @aking: That's a little creepy, but thanks. @digitxp: what a good book. I must re-read it.